# WCF service - data being rejected virtually instantly according to size despite large max values

Tags: wcf, size, max

I have a WCF webservice with 1 functioning web method that takes a single string parameter.
I have a WinForms app that references the WCF webservice and it is all running on .NET 4.0.

Problem is that when I call the web method with too much data for the string data (around 4MB) this debugging both client and server on my local machine (Win 7 Pro 64bit, IIS 7) I get the following error (inner exception, exception):

> The request was aborted: The request
>   was canceled.
>
> An error (The request was aborted: The
>   request was canceled.) occurred while
>   transmitting data over the HTTP
>   channel.

When running on the production server I get a different message (stupid I'd didn't copy it) saying something along the lines of the server may have aborted the connection or similar.

If I reduce the data to around half (2MB) it works fine. The frustrating thing is I've maxed all the config settings, reset IIS, rebooted my machine but still it remains.

The web service validation code gets hit, validates user as okay and then as soon as it exits the validation dumps the message above back to the client. The stack trace when in the validation method (my code) shows only .NET stuff so there is no more of my code to debug, 8(.

On the server side I have this in the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
    <service name="MyNS.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyNS.MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpWithMessageSecurity" contract="MyNS..MyService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyNS.MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate findValue="Server" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNS.Validators.MyServiceUserValidator, MyNS./>
            </serviceCredentials>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpWithMessageSecurity" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

On the client side I have this in the app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="serviceHttpBinding"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:20"
                 openTimeout="00:00:20"
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00">
            <readerQuotas
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                  algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientServerBehaviour">
            <clientCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://mymachine/TheServices/Services/MyService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="serviceHttpBinding"
      contract="DirectorySubmitService.IDirectorySubmitService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDirectorySubmitService">
        <identity>
            <dns value="Server" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

EDIT 1:
After enabled debug symbols in VS, after my validation code in the WCF service completes I get the following exceptions:
System.Web.HttpException: Maximum Length Exceeded
Stack: System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()

Then:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:  Maximum Length Exceeded
Stack: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.GetInputStream()

Subsequent CommunicationExceptions are related to Channels etc.. but all are the same error message.

I all so checked the app pool in IIS that was set to 30 MB as a request limit so I have run out maximum limits I can increase so this message is a real slap in the face.

Any help would be much apprecianted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the httpRuntime web.config element that I'd put to set the request limit to 50MB was being ignored because the location path I'd specified was missing a folder level, i.e. location path="MyService.svc" instead of location path="Services/MyService.svc".

The net result being it was using the default 4MB limit which of cause gave the max length exceeded message because that was exactly the case.

Doh!

Comment: This comment clued me in to the idea that the httpRuntime element needed to be in the web services config in order for the client web app to work